# I get "FileLoadException: The given assembly name or codebase was invalid." when I try to retrieve data from my database using Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework-6

The function in question:

```
public static List<Order> GetOrdersByPage(int pageNum, byte pageSize, OrderContext orderContext)
{
    const int PageOffset = 1;
    return orderContext.Orders
                        .OrderBy(c => c.OrderID)
                        .Skip(pageSize * (pageNum - PageOffset))
                        .Take(pageSize)
                        .ToList();
    /*
    return
    (
        from o in orderContext.Orders
        orderby o.OrderID descending
        select o
    ).Skip(pageSize * (pageNum - PageOffset))
        .Take(pageSize)
        .ToList();
    */
}
```

NOTE: The commented out code does(at least is supposed to) the same thing as the uncommented out code, and thus, the error still occurs.

Also, the same error occurs when I try to simply load all of the data:

```
public static List<Order> GetAllOrders(OrderContext orderContext)
{
    return
    (
        from o in orderContext.Orders
        orderby o.OrderID descending
        select o
    ).ToList();
}
```

The [error log](https://pastebin.com/zJ0Fk4vv) and the [GitHub repository](https://github.com/kperdue2002/AdvDotNetTeamSrcCntrl/tree/CRUD-Functionality).

ANOTHER NOTE: I would like to clarify that the function to add things to the database  still works. Here is the code for it:

```
public static async Task<Order> Add(Order o, OrderContext orderContext)
{
    return await OrderAction(o, orderContext, EntityState.Added);
}

private static async Task<Order> OrderAction( Order o, OrderContext orderContext, EntityState state)
{
    orderContext.Orders.Add(o);
    orderContext.Entry(o).State = state;
    await orderContext.SaveChangesAsync();
    return o;
}
```

I made GetOrdersByPage() nonasynchronous due to me thinking that might have been part of the issue. I'll add it back once I know what really went wrong.

Comment: In short, i think it is a assembly version problem. Does it happens when you debug, only on -another- deployed environment?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your talking about, but I'll tell you that this error has occurred on two different machines.

The database is also stored locally. I'm developing this for a school assignment.

Comment: I am not sure if this solves it, but you have multiple target frameworks in `packages.config`. Both `net461` and `net472` are mentioned, and you project target is set to `v4.6.1`.

Comment: Hm, that's interesting. What do you suggest I do? I ran `Update-Package -Reinstall` to set all the instances of `net472` to `net461`, but the error still occurs.

Comment: And did the `packages.config` change, so all target frameworks was `net461` ?

Comment: Yes it did.....